# Can I combine the bind event for two selectors in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have the following:

```
   $('#loginLink')
        .bind('click', accessLinkClick);
    $('#registerLink')
        .bind('click', accessLinkClick);


function accessLinkClick(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#registerLink').unbind('click', accessLinkClick);
    $('#loginLink').unbind('click', accessLinkClick);
    dialog(this);
}
```

Is it possible for me to somehow combine the selectors for loginLink and register link so I don't need to specify them twice. I saw how to do this with functions but not events.

Comment: maybe with a css class that both links share and that you could use as selector.

Answer (score 3):

yeah by comma

```
$('#loginLink, #registerLink')
        .bind('click', accessLinkClick);
```

For reference [Read here](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/)

Comment: thanks. I thought I had to do use each. Seems very easy now you told me how.